# UITextView not scrollable - text changes when resized

Tags: ios

I'm having a problem with UITextViews, in particular I would like to have a textview which is not scrollable (only showing text), but the content that is shown changes when the textview resizes:[image: Initial load][image: After resizing]

In both images the textview is the same size (frame) but for some reason it cuts properly after it is resized post-load.

Some background:
1) this problem only occurs in nested views (it the textview is directly in the view controller it is fine)
View controller
-> Custom subview
----> text view

Here is the code for the custom subview to reproduce the issue:
https://gist.github.com/pfaucon/6f7c2ba0328ce38cb22b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not calling [textView sizeToFit] when I set the frame the first time (but I did every other time).